# How to use replacement patterns as a CSS class for View?

Tags: 7, views

I am trying to figure out how I can use a replacement pattern in the "Other > CSS Class" setting for a view. For example, I would like the View to contain a css class of classname-[nid] with the Node ID as part of the class. Adding the replacement pattern to the CSS Class field results in "Error message - CSS classes must be alphanumeric or dashes only." Does anyone know a creative way to get a field value into the CSS Class, or otherwise apply a field value as part of the overall View class?

Comment: Including node IDs would create overly-specific CSS selectors. If you do this, you will need to update your CSS classes by hand every time you publish a new node. It would help to know what you are trying to accomplish by doing this; there may be a better approach.

Comment: Sure. Let's say I am creating a View of tshirts with several block displays. Each block contains a filter based on the "color" field...a block for red shirts, a block for green shirts, etc. I'd like to be able to apply a CSS class containing the value of the color field.

Comment: If each of the color has a separate Block Display then set a different color to it as the CSS class. The global Views CSS can't contain replacement patterns, only View Rows and Fields can take Replacement tokens. Or are you using a Contextual filter to sort the colors automatically? You can add that logic to your theme, print out a class to Views depending on the Contextual filter value.